# Due to heightAnchor, not able to scroll the collectionview vertically

Tags: ios, swift

Using the custom UICollectionViewLayout for collection view. To show the collection view properly for all the iPhone, i am using heightAnchor. After applying heightAnchor, i am not able to scroll vertically. Please help me.

This is for collectionview vertical scroll issue due to heightAnchor.

```
customizeCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
customizeCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:customizeCollectionView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
customizeCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.size.width).isActive = true
customizeCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.topAnchor , constant:(((20 + (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!) + self.layer.frame.height))).isActive = true
customizeCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.leftAnchor , constant:39).isActive = true
```

collection view should scroll vertically but actually it is not scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 customizeCollectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:customizeCollectionView.contentSize.height).isActive = true
```

You cannot set the height of a collection view related to its content view. It should be always related to its supper view.

Comment: I understand but setting height should not stop the vertical scrolling right ? Do you have any idea about it

Comment: You are setting it as per contentsize so it does not scroll. because the height is equal to total no of cells in it.

Comment: Okay Mahak so what should i set as heightAnchor

Comment: Thank you guys. I have recalculated the height and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

CollectionView is similar to scrollView. You don't have to give height constraint for scrollView/collectionView, You need to set Dynamic height of content view.

Comment: I am setting the Dynamic height in customeCollectionViewFlowLayout. and accessing same and applying it in heightAnchor.

Comment: setting the dynamic height of content view is different thing.